# jQuery mouse events not working after scrolling through list

Tags: javascript, css, dom, jquery

I've got a div that has a height of 240px with an overflow that's hidden (css attr.). When the user presses a button, the div scrolls up to the other content that was hidden before. When a user then leaves this div, I want it to scroll back to the default content. However, no jQuery mouse event is working... Does anyone know why? Here's my code:

```
<div id="wrapper">
    <ul>     
        <li id="centerhover">
            <div class="welcomemsg">
                welcome info
            </div>

        <div class="share">
            <ul>
                <li>share 1</li>
                <li>share 2</li>
            </ul>
        </div> 
        </li>
        <li id="center">
            <div id="pull"></div>
        </li>   
    </ul>
</div>
```

The initial content that's shown is in the list item with id "center". When a user presses the div with id "pull", the content in list item with id "centerhover" should be shown. Here's the Javascript behind it:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
        $("#pull").click(function() {
            return gotoPage(0);
        });

        $("centerhover").click(function() {
            return gotoPage(1);
        });

        function gotoPage(page) {
            var visible = Math.ceil($("#wrapper").innerHeight() / 240);
            var currentpage = 1;
            if (page == 1) {
                currentpage = 0;
            }
            var dir = page < 1 ? -1 : 1;
            var n = Math.abs(currentpage - page);
            var top = 240 * dir * visible * n;
            $("#wrapper").filter(':not(:animated)').animate({
                scrollTop : '+=' + top}, 500, function() {
                    if (page == 1) {
                        $("#wrapper").scrollTop(240);
                    } else {
                        $("#wrapper").scrollTop(-240);
                    }
            });
            return false;
        }

        var center = document.getElementById("center");
        var wrapper = document.getElementById("wrapper");
        wrapper.scrollTop = center.scrollHeight;
        setTimeout(function() {
            T.preload(0);
            T.poll(0);
        }, 1000);
    });
```

Anyone has got an idea? I've tried mouseout, click and other events... Thanks!

Comment: wow... Normally I'd throw out an answer but the number of incorrect issues in your above script are likely part if not all of your problem.  First and foremost, if you're using JQuery why are you using document.get*.  Use var wrapper = $("#wrapper");  Also your event ties need to be in $("#wrapper").bind("mouseleave", function(){....});   If I remember later tonight and nobody comes by and takes what I said here and makes an answer, I'll give you your solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First pass just to point out some of the changes to your script, nowhere do I see an attempt to bind a "mouseleave" event to the existing script, I will put what you would want to do below the modified code below (NOTE for all Flamers:  This was a 20 second pass at fixing some of his syntax issues, I will be refactoring as time allows)

```
$(document).ready(function() {
        $("#pull").click(function() {
            return gotoPage(0);
        });

        $("#centerhover").click(function() {
            return gotoPage(1);
        });

        function gotoPage(page) {
            var visible = Math.ceil($("#wrapper").innerHeight() / 240);
            var currentpage = 1;
            if (page == 1) {
                currentpage = 0;
            }
            var dir = page < 1 ? -1 : 1;
            var n = Math.abs(currentpage - page);
            var top = 240 * dir * visible * n;
            $("#wrapper").filter(':not(:animated)').animate({
                scrollTop : '+=' + parseInt(top)}, 500, function() {
                    if (page == 1) {
                        $("#wrapper").scrollTop(240);
                    } else {
                        $("#wrapper").scrollTop(-240);
                    }
            });
            return false;
        }

        var center = $("#center");
        var wrapper = $("#wrapper");
        wrapper.scrollTop(center.scrollTop());
        setTimeout(function() {
            T.preload(0);
            T.poll(0);
        }, 1000);
    });
```

To add a bind to leaving the wrapper element:

```
$("#wrapper").bind("mouseleave", function(){
    $(this).scrollTop(0);
});
```

Comment: Ok.. I made some stupid errors and your solution works! However, I've got some questions. What's the difference between a bind on mouseleave and the jQuery mouseout() function? I don't know why I mixed plain jQuery and Javascript, but it is that bad? :) Thanks!

Comment: First, if you're using JQuery don't ever mix it in with getElementBy* code.  JQuery handles all the cross browser issues you can run into while straight javascript does not.  So yes, it is that bad.

Onto your next question, you can read the full description of the differences on JQuery.com, but mouseleave / mouseout behave only slightly differently.  I would imagine the above sample will work with "mouseout", it's just the binding call that fixes the issue.  Glad it worked, as I wasn't done refactoring but I didn't get around to it last night.  Cheers!